# Как реализовать остановку потока перед запуском нового его экземпляра?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Помогите разрулить потоки. Я не буду предоставлять код, мне нужна просто идея.

Есть некоторое событие, по которому запускается некоторый поток. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы каждый запуск этого потока завершал выполнение предыдущего экземпляра.

Framework 4.0 (без async / await)

Comment: сохраняй запущенный поток, и при событии просто аборть его :)

Comment: Остановить поток и запустить его заново - не?

Comment: смотря что делает сам поток, если его можно просто прервать без последствий для данных с которыми он работает, то вариант Grundy, Если нужно послать команду на правильное завершение, то можно копнуть класс `Task` и `CancellationToken`

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, да, только существует несколько способов это сделать и те, которые я попробовал меня по непонятным причинами подводили. Просто зависали на ожидании завершения потока при запуске механизма отмены. Поэтому я решил не изобретать велосипед а прокатиться на вашем, если вы не против, конечно )

Comment: @iRumba Ну тут я могу сказать только одно: TerminateThread(), если у вас, конечно, реальный поток

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Старый" и самый топорный способ заключается в создании потока и его убийстве при необходимости. Однако потенциально это весьма опасный способ, т.к., например, поток может оставить общие данные в неконсистентном состоянии или вовсе [отказаться завершаться](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.resetabort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
class Program
{
    private static Thread _thread;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
        TriggerEventOld();

        Console.ReadLine();
        TriggerEventOld();

        // дождемся завершения
        _thread.Join();
    }

    private static void TriggerEventOld()
    {
        if (_thread != null)
        {
            _thread.Abort();
            // корректнее будет дождаться завершения
            _thread.Join();
        }

        _thread = new Thread(Foo);
        _thread.Start();
    }

    private static void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo started");

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500); 
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo aborted");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Foo ended");
    }
}
```

---

[Лучше не связываться](http://joeduffyblog.com/2009/03/13/managed-code-and-asynchronous-exception-hardening/) с `Abort()`, и использовать "мягкое" завершения потока с помощью `ManualResetEventSlim`, который послужит флагом завершения. У такого способа есть один минус -- если вы запускаете синхронный код, который может долго отвечать (например, чтение файла или запрос в сеть), то придется долго ждать завершения потока при новом запуске.

```
class Program
{
    private static Thread _thread;
    private static ManualResetEventSlim _reset = new ManualResetEventSlim();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
        TriggerEventOld();

        Console.ReadLine();
        TriggerEventOld();

        // дождемся завершения
        _thread.Join();
    }

    private static void TriggerEventOld()
    {
        if (_thread != null)
        {
            _reset.Set();
            // корректнее будет дождаться завершения
            _thread.Join();
        }

        _thread = new Thread(Foo);
        _reset.Reset();
        _thread.Start();
    }

    private static void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo started");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (_reset.IsSet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Foo canceled");
                break;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(500); 
        }

        if (!_reset.IsSet)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo ended");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Но поскольку вы используете .NET 4.0, значит вам доступен TPL. В таком случае будет лучше воспользоваться `Task` и `CancellationToken`, с ними вы можете сделать "мягкую" остановку задачи. Преимущество новой модели заключается в том, что практически все асинхронные методы поддерживают остановку с помощью `CancellationToken`, поэтому код будет реагировать на завершение быстрее.

```
class Program
{
    private static Task _task;
    private static CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
        TriggerEventNew();

        Console.ReadLine();
        TriggerEventNew();

        // дождемся завершения;
        // этот вызов может выбросить исключение,
        // если внутри возникнет необработанное исключение
        _task.Wait();
    }

    private static void TriggerEventNew()
    {
        if (_task != null)
        {
            _cts.Cancel();
            // корректнее будет дождаться завершения;
            // этот вызов может выбросить исключение,
            // если внутри возникнет необработанное исключение
            _task.Wait();
        }

        // пересоздаем каждый раз, поскольку это одноразовый объект
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FooNew(_cts.Token), _cts.Token);
    }

    private static void FooNew(CancellationToken token)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FooNew started");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FooNew aborted");
                break;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FooNew ended");
        }
    }
}
```

Если будете использовать `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`, не забудьте обернуть код в блок `try/catch` c проверкой токена:

```
try
{
    ...
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    ...
}
catch (OperationCanceledException e)
{
    if (e.CancellationToken != token)
    {
        // отмена была вызвана не нами, бросаем исключение
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что если мы в потоке вызываем "чужой" метод, который понятия не имеет про наши токены и потоки, то прервать его можно только первым способом?

Comment: @rdorn да, правильно.

Comment: @rdorn в таких случаях будет безопаснее вызывать такой код в отдельном *процессе* и убивать процесс. Но, как обычно, it depends.

Comment: Ну у меня плагины грузятся в отдельный домен, для приложения угрозы нет, а плагин о своей безопасности пусть сам заботится. Просто не был уверен, что это единственный вариант

Comment: @rdorn да, для плагинов с чужим кодом аппдомены -- самый разумный вариант.

Comment: Добавлю, что `CancellationToken` можно использовать не только с задачами, но и с потоками.

Comment: @rdorn если речь идет о плагине - то лучше ему сначала послать "мягкую" просьбу завершиться, а после истечения тайм-аута выгрузить AppDomain.

Comment: @PavelMayorov это понятно, для своих плагинов так и делаю. Проблема с чужими. В интерфейсе же не пропишешь требование правильно обрабатывать токен, исключения и не пытаться повиснуть, максимум наличие свойства с токеном, которое запросто можно игнорировать, ну есть оно и есть. Даже метод Stop() предусмотрен интерфейсом, но ни что не мешает повесть на него пустышку.

Comment: @rdorn так потому и пишу: *"после истечения тайм-аута выгрузить AppDomain"*. Специально для тех плагинов, которые на `Stop()` повесили пустышку.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Кстати, AppDomain не получится выгрузить, если он висит в `finally`.

Answer (score -2):

В итоге я придумал собственное решение. Если его немного развить, то можно и под другие задачи приспособить. Но мне достаточно такого функционала.

```
public class TaskQueue
{
    Task _worker;
    Queue<Action> _queue;
    int _maxTasks;
    bool _deleteOld;
    object _lock = new object();

    public TaskQueue(int maxTasks, bool deleteOld = true)
    {
        if (maxTasks < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("TaskQueue: максимальное число задач должно быть больше 0");
        _maxTasks = maxTasks;
        _deleteOld = deleteOld;
        _queue = new Queue<Action>(maxTasks);
    }

    public bool Add(Action action)
    {
        if (_queue.Count() < _maxTasks)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(action);
            DoWorkAsync();
            return true;
        }
        if (_deleteOld)
        {
            _queue.Dequeue();
            return Add(action);
        }
        return false;
    }

    void DoWorkAsync()
    {
        if(_queue.Count>0)
            _worker = Task.Factory.StartNew(DoWork);
    }

    void DoWork()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_queue.Count > 0)
            {
                _queue.Dequeue().Invoke();
                DoWork();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь все просто. Есть очередь задач определенного размера и флагом, говорящим о том, удалять ли старые задачи в случае переполнения очереди. То есть я добавляю задачу, она пытается добавиться в очередь. Если в очереди есть свободное место, добавляется, если нет, то либо не добавляется, либо удаляет из очереди старую задачу (которая следующая на выполнение). Далее запускается обработчик очереди, который, если не выполняется другая задача, берет задачу из очереди и запускает. После завершения запускается рекурсивно.

Comment: Есть много вопросов к коду. Тип не потокобезопасен. Неясно, зачем нужен второй вызов `Task.Factory.StartNew()` в `DoWork()`. Вызов чужого кода внутри лока может обернуться проблемами. И т.д.

Comment: @andreycha, думаю, из вопроса было понятно, насколько я шарю в многопоточности. Итак, что значит "не потокобезопасен"? Чем это грозит? Желательно пример, при котором может вылететь артефакт или исключение. Хотя бы словами. `Task.Factory.StartNew(_queue.Dequeue())` в `DoWork()` - это собственно запуск самого `Action`, который передал в него программист. Если вы не заметили, в параметрах `Add` не `Task`, а `Action`. Какими проблемами может обернуться вызов чужого кода внутри лока? Нужна конкретика.

Comment: @andreycha, да, по поводу `StartNew` в `DoWork` вы правы. Исправил.

Comment: Если нужна асинхронная очередь, то лучше использовать BufferBlock https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh873173(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Serginio, я ведь написал `Framework 4.0 (без async / await)`

Comment: @iRumba Прошу прощения, заметил только тогда когда написал

Comment: @iRumba само обращение к `Queue` из нескольких потоков может привести к ошибкам -- надо использовать `ConcurrentQueue`. Даже если `Add()` вызывается из одного потока, `DoWork()` уже будет работать в других потоках. И пересечение `Enqueue()`/`Dequeue()` из разных потоков может привести к неожиданному поведению или исключению.

Comment: @iRumba однако даже при использовании `ConcurrentQueue` возможно получить неожиданное поведение. Например, вы создаете очередь на 1 задачу. И вызываете `Add()` параллельно из N потоков. По-хорошему, должна выполниться только та задача, которая придет последней. Но вполне вероятно, что задач выполнится несколько или даже все, поскольку одновременно несколько потоков могут пройти условие `if (_queue.Count() < _maxTasks)` и добавиться в очередь.

Comment: @iRumba по поводу выполнения чужого кода под локом я ошибся. В вашем случае это как раз то, что нужно, чтобы гарантировать запуск следующей задачи только после окончания предыдущей.