# Завершение потока из другого потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность, c#-faq

Например, есть несколько практически одинаковых потоков, которые могут длиться до бесконечности

инициализация:

```
 ParameterizedThreadStart pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(runMethod);
 Thread t = new Thread(pts);            
 t.Start(values);
```

поток:

```
 void run(object p)
 {
      // нужен поток, который повторяет одно и то же с некоторой переодичностью, поэтому так:

      while(true)
      {
           // что-то делаем
           doAnything(p);

           Thread.Sleep(60000);
      }
 }
```

Вопрос в том, как их адекватно прервать? Было бы здорово, если их прервать можно было прервать пока они спят или хотя бы после doAnything();

можно в основном потоке сделать что-то вроде

```
 Thread t = new Thread(pts);            
 t.Start(values);
 ...
 t.Abort();
```

но я не уверен, что в потоке не прервется какая-то важная операция - загрузка/удаление/обработка файла или транзакция какая-то незакомитится

Comment: Кажется, этот вопрос тут уже несколько раз задавался - но те разы были не настолько "чистыми", в них примешивались другие проблемы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как реализовать остановку потока перед запуском нового его экземпляра?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573579/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: @andreycha я понимаю, что там вы ответили примерно то же самое что и я - но вопросы-то разные! Здесь вопрос более общий.

Comment: @andreycha потоки нужно останавливать не только перед запуском нового экземпляра, но и, к примеру, перед остановкой сервиса.

Comment: Может не в тему, но я не понимаю зачем это все, если на дворе 2016 год C# 6.0 , .Net 4.6 и существует TPL и async/await ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Красивее всего это делается через механизм [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx). Этот механизм специально создан для передачи сообщений об остановки и отмене между потоками:

```
void run(object p)
{
  var ct = (CancellationToken)p;

  do
  {
       // что-то делаем
       doAnything(p);
  } while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested && !ct.WaitHandle.WaitOne(60000));
}
```

Здесь я использую ожидание на событии как прерываемую альтернативу `Thread.Sleep`. Если ожидание успешно - значит, поток надо останавливать. Если неуспешно (тайм-аут ожидания) - значит, можно продолжать работу.

Перед ожиданием я проверяю `IsCancellationRequested`, чтобы не создавать событие ядра когда этого не требуется.

Создание такого потока:

```
using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource()) {
    new Thread(run).Start(cts.Token);
    ...
    cts.Cancel();
}
```

Также вместо потока можно использовать задачу (`Task.Run`). В таком случае для ожидания лучше использовать `Task.Delay`, это позволит обойтись вовсе без объектов ядра:

```
async Task run(CancellationToken ct)
{
  do
  {
       // что-то делаем
       doAnything(p);

       await Task.Delay(60000, ct);
  } while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested);
}

Task.Run(() => run(cts.Token));
```

Бонусом к использованию `CancellationToken` идет возможность передачи `ct` дальше в `doAnything` - благодаря чему вы можете тонко выбирать, в какие моменты допустимо прерывание обработки.

Если вы будете использовать асинхронный вариант - то практически все асинхронные функции стандартной библиотеки также умеют принимать `CancellationToken`, что позволяет безопасно прервать любую долгую операцию, если вы того пожелаете.

---

В более старых рантаймах, где механизма `CancellationToken` нет, для той же цели можно использовать [`ManualResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx). Принцип тот же - вместо вызова `Thread.Sleep` ждем на событии и проверяем результат.

Comment: С наличием в языке лямбд необходимость в передаче объекта в поток и каста в `CancellationToken` по идее не так велика. Хотя ваш код объявлен как код для старой версии языка, так что...

Comment: @VladD честно говоря, не вижу смысла городить лямбду по любому поводу

Comment: Ну, для типобезопасности я бы не пожалел лямбды. Но это уже вопрос личных предпочтений.

Answer (score 6):

Есть более подробный ответ  [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474945/is-it-safe-to-use-a-boolean-flag-to-stop-a-thread-from-running-in-c-sharp) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071302/stopping-work-from-one-thread-using-another-thread)

1. Самый простой вариант создать `boolean` переменную, которая отслеживает запрос на завершение потока. Данный вариант не позволяет прервать `Thread.Sleep`.

   ```
   boolean volatile isRunning = true;

   void run(object p)
   {
      while(true)
      {
         if (!isRunning) break; // exit if not running

         doAnything(p);

         Thread.Sleep(60000);
      }
   }
   ```
2. Другой вариант использовать [CancellationTokenSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx). Подходит начиная с .net 4

Comment: `bool`-переменная не позволит оборвать `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: Да, верно, поправил, хотел описать все варианты возможные, начиная с самых примитивных, но увидел что уже подробно ответ опубликовали пока я писал первый.