# Как правильно остановить Thread?

Tags: c#, клавиатура

Язык C#, Visual Studio 2013. Скажите пожалуйста, как в **консольном** приложении обработать нажатия клавиши, чтобы остановить работающий Thread? Не могу найти класса с соответствующим событием, именно, для консольного приложения.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573594/198316

Comment: С чем именно у вас проблема? С остановкой потока? тогда ответ VladD и ссылка выше должны прояснить ситуацию. Или с организацией работы с клавиатурой? Да, у консоли нет событий, но это можно решить разными способами.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Никак. Thread должен сотрудничать, и сам останавливаться, когда его попросят.

Например, при помощи разделяемой переменной (но не забудьте о синхронизации при помощи `lock`):

```
object mutex = new object();
bool stop = false;

var t = new Thread(() =>
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        // тут сделать что-то полезное, например:
        Console.WriteLine(i++);
        // проверка на выход
        lock (mutex)
        {
            if (stop)
                break;
        }
    }
});
t.Start();

Console.ReadKey();
lock (mutex) stop = true;
t.Join();
```

---

Вот вам более современный метод, без `Thread` и `Sleep`, через `Task` и `CancellationToken`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var task = Task.Run(() => Work(cts.Token));

    Console.ReadKey();
    cts.Cancel();
    task.Wait(); // для асинхронной функции тут лучше await task
}

static async Task Work(CancellationToken ct)
{
    try
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(500, ct);
            Console.WriteLine(i++);
            // после длинных операций внутри цикла имеет смысл вставлять
            //if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            //    return;
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        // нас останавливают, выходим
    }
}
```

`CancellationToken` — это правильный метод передавать сообщения о завершении, используйте его по возможности.

---

Спасибо @rdorn и @Pavel Mayorov за подсказки в комментариях, которые помогли значительно улучшить ответ.

Comment: за что вы не любите CancelationToken? =)

Comment: @rdorn: Я его нежно люблю :) Сейчас дополню.

Comment: Почему не `while(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)`?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Тогда уж нужно и Delay с `CancellationToken`'ом вызывать. Исправил, спасибо!

Comment: А зачем ловить `OperationCanceledException`, кто его выкинет?

Comment: @Monk: `await Task.Delay(500, ct);`

Comment: Т.е. если вместо делея там нормальный код, который не умеет кидать исключения - то этот перехват не нужен?

Comment: @Monk: Именно так. Но достаточно часто `CancellationToken` используют в `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`, так что обычно блок try/catch нужен.