# Принудительная отмена задачи

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, tpl

Везде написано, что работа с задачами- это кооперативный процесс, т.е задача должна сама корректно завершится при первой просьбе из внешнего кода.

Но, что делать если кто-то подводит?

Например, я делаю `Cancel` на токене и даю на завершение некоторое время, но задача не завершается, а код должен двигаться дальше. Оставлять висеть задачу?

Читал, что есть `Thread.Abort`, но его не рекомендуют использовать.

---

Пример с выносом стороннего кода в отдельный процесс был приведен.

Хотелось бы увидеть еще какие-нибудь способы, еще как минимум решение задачи через appDomain.

Comment: Ничего. Не использовать код, который не надёжен. Механизма безопасной принудительной остановки любого кода, что нативного, что управляемого, нету.

Comment: Если очень хочется, вынесите код в другой AppDomain или вообще процесс.

Comment: @VladD, можно пример с AppDomain и отдельным процессом? Сценарий такой, который я описал в вопросе: Задача не выполнилась за определенное время и ее нужно прибить.

Comment: Я напишу попозже. Учтите, что работа с AppDomain'ом медленная и требует сериализации.

Comment: Вроде обсуждали уже (см в т.ч. комментарии): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573579/106

Comment: @andreycha, вроде, похоже по смыслу, но нету примеров реализаций.=(

Comment: Может находить ID потока по какому-то признаку (например, по времени старта), и скармливать API-функции TerminateThread?

Comment: @VadimTagil: И это настолько же плохо, насколько и `Thread.Abort`.

Comment: @VladD Это (для Task) не работает, как оказалось. Точнее работает (поток действительно завершается), но после этого портиться состояние ThreadPool и приложение начинает крашиться или зависать в случайных местах.

Comment: Попробовал у Task задать флаг LongRunning, в этом случае вроде получается ее убивать через TerminateThread, не нарушая работу приложения.

Comment: Зря вы не хотите использовать thread.Abort(). При его вызове внутри потока срабатывает исключение ThreadAbortException, вам нужно всего-навсего реализовать метод остановки всех процессов в потоке в соответствующем блоке catch

Answer (score 8):

Ну вот вам пример реализации. Сразу предупреждаю, кода будет много.

Возьмём в качестве основы вот такую ненадёжную функцию:

```
class EvilComputation
{
    static Random random = new Random();

    public static async Task<double> Compute(
                int numberOfSeconds, double x, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        bool wellBehaved = random.Next(2) == 0;
        var y = x * x;
        var delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(numberOfSeconds);
        await Task.Delay(delay, wellBehaved ? ct : CancellationToken.None);
        return y;
    }
}
```

Вы видим, что функция плохая: она может в зависимости от случайных условий не реагировать на отмену.

Что делать в этом случае? Вынесем функцию в отдельный процесс. Этот процесс можно будет убить без особого вреда для исходного процесса.

Для того, чтобы вызвать функцию в другом процессе, нужно передать данные о вызове функции туда. Для связи используем, например, анонимные пайпы (можно использовать по сути что угодно). Я основываю код на этом примере: [How to: Use Anonymous Pipes for Local Interprocess Communication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102(v=vs.110).aspx).

Для передачи данных будем использовать стандартное бинарное форматирование, раз уж мы не пошли через WCF. Нам нужны DTO-объекты, которые будут перебрасываться между процессами. Их нужно использовать в двух процессах — главном и вспомогательном (назовём его *плагином*), поэтому для DTO-типов понадобится отдельная сборка.

Заводим сборку `OutProcCommonData`, кладём в неё следующие классы:

```
namespace OutProcCommonData
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Command // общий класс-предок для посылаемой команды
    {
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Evaluate : Command // команда на вычисление
    {
        public int NumberOfSecondsToProcess;
        public double X;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Cancel : Command // команда на отмену
    {
    }
}
```

Далее, возвращаемый результат:

```
namespace OutProcCommonData
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Response // общий класс-предок для возвращаемого результата
    {
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Result : Response // готовый результат вычислений
    {
        public double Y;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Error : Response // ошибка с текстом
    {
        public string Text;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Cancelled : Response // подтверждение отмены
    {
    }
}
```

---

Далее, наш плагин. Это отдельное консольное приложение (хотя, если мы не хотим видеть консоль и отладочный вывод, можно сделать его неконсольным).

Протокол общения таков. Главная программа посылает `Evaluate`, а после него, возможно, `Cancel`. Плагин возвращает `Result` в случае успешного вычисления, `Cancelled` в случае полученного сигнала отмены и успешно отменённого вычисления, и `Error` в случае ошибки (например, нарушения протокола коммуникации).

Вот обвязочный код:

```
class Plugin
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        // нам должны быть переданы два аргумента: хендл входящего и исходящего пайпов
        if (args.Length != 2)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Shouldn't be started directly");
            return 1;
        }

        return new Plugin().Run(args[0], args[1]).Result;
    }

    BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter(); // для сериализации

    async Task<int> Run(string hIn, string hOut)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[Plugin] Running");
        // открывем переданные пайпы
        using (var inStream = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.In, hIn))
        using (var outStream = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.Out, hOut))
        {
            try
            {
                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); // токен для отмены
                Console.WriteLine("[Plugin] Reading args");
                // пытаемся десериализовать аргументы
                var args = SafeGet<OutProcCommonData.Evaluate>(inStream);
                if (args == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[Plugin] Didn't get args");
                    // отправляем ошибку, если не удалось
                    serializer.Serialize(
                        outStream,
                        new OutProcCommonData.Error() { Text = "Unrecognized input" });
                    // и выходим
                    return 3;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("[Plugin] Got args, start compute and waiting cancel");
                // запускаем вычисление
                var computeTask =
                        EvilComputation.Compute(
                            args.NumberOfSecondsToProcess,
                            args.X,
                            cts.Token);
                // параллельно запускаем чтение возможной отмены
                var waitForCancelTask = Task.Run(() =>
                        (OutProcCommonData.Cancel)serializer.Deserialize(inStream));
                // дожидаемся одного из двух
                var winner = await Task.WhenAny(computeTask, waitForCancelTask);
                // если первой пришла отмена...
                if (winner == waitForCancelTask)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[Plugin] Got cancel, cancelling computation");
                    // просим вычисление завершиться
                    cts.Cancel();
                }
                // окончания вычисления всё равно нужно дождаться
                Console.WriteLine("[Plugin] Awaiting computation");
                // если вычисление отменится, здесь будет исключение
                var result = await computeTask;
                Console.WriteLine("[Plugin] Sending back result");
                // отсылаем результат в пайп
                serializer.Serialize(
                    outStream,
                    new OutProcCommonData.Result() { Y = result });
                // нормальный выход
                return 0;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // мы успешно отменили задание, рапортуем
                Console.WriteLine("[Plugin] Sending cancellation");
                serializer.Serialize(
                    outStream,
                    new OutProcCommonData.Cancelled());
                return 2;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // возникла непредвиденная ошибка, рапортуем
                Console.WriteLine($"[Plugin] Sending error {ex.Message}");
                serializer.Serialize(
                    outStream,
                    new OutProcCommonData.Error() { Text = ex.Message });
                return 3;
            }
        }
    }

    // ну и вспомогательная функция, которая пытается читать данные из пайпа
    T SafeGet<T>(Stream s) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(s);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Я не отлавливаю ошибки при записи в пайп, добавьте сами по вкусу.

---

Теперь, главная программа. Она будет у нас отдельно от плагина (то есть, у нас получаются *три* сборки).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().Run().Wait();

    async Task Run()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        try
        {
            var y = await ComputeOutProc(2, cts.Token);
            Console.WriteLine($"[Main] Result: {y}");
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[Main] Timed out");
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[Main] Cancelled");
        }
    }

    const int SecondsToSend = 3;
    const int TimeoutSeconds = 5;
    const int CancelSeconds = 2;

    BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
    async Task<double> ComputeOutProc(double x, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        Process plugin = null;
        bool pluginStarted = false;
        try
        {
            // создаём исходящий и входящий пайпы
            using (var commandStream = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(
                            PipeDirection.Out, HandleInheritability.Inheritable))
            using (var responseStream = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(
                            PipeDirection.In, HandleInheritability.Inheritable))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[Main] Starting plugin");
                plugin = new Process()
                {
                    StartInfo =
                    {
                        FileName = "OutProcPlugin.exe",
                        Arguments = commandStream.GetClientHandleAsString() + " " +
                                    responseStream.GetClientHandleAsString(),
                        UseShellExecute = false
                    }
                };
                // запускаем плагин с параметрами
                plugin.Start();
                pluginStarted = true;
                Console.WriteLine("[Main] Started plugin");

                commandStream.DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle();
                responseStream.DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle();

                void Send(Command c)
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(commandStream, c);
                    commandStream.Flush();
                }

                try
                {
                    // отсылаем плагину команду на вычисление
                    Console.WriteLine("[Main] Sending evaluate request");
                    Send(new OutProcCommonData.Evaluate()
                    {
                        NumberOfSecondsToProcess = SecondsToSend,
                        X = x
                    });

                    Task<Response> responseTask;
                    bool readyInTime;
                    bool cancellationSent = false;
                    // внутри этого блока при отмене будем отсылать команду плагину
                    using (ct.Register(() =>
                        {
                            Send(new OutProcCommonData.Cancel());
                            Console.WriteLine("[Main] Requested cancellation");
                            cancellationSent = true;
                        }))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[Main] Starting getting response");
                        // ожидаем получение ответа
                        responseTask = Task.Run(() =>
                                (Response)serializer.Deserialize(responseStream));
                        // или таймаута
                        var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeoutSeconds));
                        var winner = await Task.WhenAny(responseTask, timeoutTask);
                        readyInTime = winner == responseTask;
                    }

                    // если наступил таймаут, просим процесс вежливо завершить вычисления
                    if (!readyInTime)
                    {
                        if (!cancellationSent)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("[Main] Not ready in time, sending cancel");
                            Send(new OutProcCommonData.Cancel());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("[Main] Not ready in time, cancel sent");
                        }
                        // и ждём ещё немного, ну или прихода ответа
                        var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(CancelSeconds));
                        await Task.WhenAny(responseTask, timeoutTask);
                    }

                    // если до сих пор ничего не пришло, плагин завис, убиваем его
                    if (!responseTask.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[Main] No response, killing plugin");
                        plugin.Kill(); // это завершит ожидание с исключением, по идее
                                       // в ранних версиях .NET нужно было бы поймать
                                       // это исключение
                                       // и уходим с исключением-таймаутом
                        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        throw new TimeoutException();
                    }

                    // здесь мы уверены, что ожидание завершилось
                    Console.WriteLine("[Main] Obtaining response");
                    var response = await responseTask; // тут может быть брошено исключение

                    // если была затребована отмена, выходим
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    // проверяем тип результата:
                    switch (response)
                    {
                    case Result r:
                        // нормальный результат, возвращаем его
                        Console.WriteLine("[Main] Got result, returning");
                        return r.Y;
                    case Cancelled _:
                        // отмена не по ct = таймаут
                        Console.WriteLine("[Main] Got cancellation");
                        throw new TimeoutException();
                    case Error err:
                        // пришла ошибка, бросаем исключение
                        // лучше, конечно, определить собственный тип здесь
                        Console.WriteLine("[Main] Got error");
                        throw new Exception(err.Text);
                    default:
                        // сюда мы вообще не должны попасть, если плагин работает нормально
                        Console.WriteLine("[Main] Unexpected error");
                        throw new Exception("Unexpected response type");
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[Main] IO error occured");
                    throw new Exception("IO Error", e);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (pluginStarted)
            {
                plugin.WaitForExit();
                plugin.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Результат пробега:

```
[Main] Starting plugin
[Main] Started plugin
[Main] Sending evaluate request
[Main] Starting getting response
[Plugin] Running
[Plugin] Reading args
[Plugin] Got args, start compute and waiting cancel
[Plugin] Awaiting computation
[Plugin] Sending back result
[Main] Obtaining response
[Main] Got result, returning
[Main] Result: 4
```

Если поменять константу `SecondsToSend` на 10, чтобы был таймаут, получаем такой результат двух пробегов:

Для штатного завершения:

```
[Main] Starting plugin
[Main] Started plugin
[Main] Sending evaluate request
[Main] Starting getting response
[Plugin] Running
[Plugin] Reading args
[Plugin] Got args, start compute and waiting cancel
[Main] Not ready in time, sending cancel
[Plugin] Got cancel, cancelling computation
[Plugin] Awaiting computation
[Plugin] Sending cancellation
[Main] Obtaining response
[Main] Got cancellation
[Main] Timed out
```

Для принудительного завершения:

```
[Main] Starting plugin
[Main] Started plugin
[Main] Sending evaluate request
[Main] Starting getting response
[Plugin] Running
[Plugin] Reading args
[Plugin] Got args, start compute and waiting cancel
[Main] Not ready in time, sending cancel
[Plugin] Got cancel, cancelling computation
[Plugin] Awaiting computation
[Main] No response, killing plugin
[Main] Timed out
```

Если добавить перед

```
var y = await ComputeOutProc(2, cts.Token);
```

преждевременную отмену:

```
cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

получим такой результат: для штатного завершения

```
[Main] Starting plugin
[Main] Started plugin
[Main] Sending evaluate request
[Main] Starting getting response
[Plugin] Running
[Plugin] Reading args
[Plugin] Got args, start compute and waiting cancel
[Main] Requested cancellation
[Plugin] Got cancel, cancelling computation
[Plugin] Awaiting computation
[Plugin] Sending cancellation
[Main] Obtaining response
[Main] Cancelled
```

и для принудительного завершения

```
[Main] Starting plugin
[Main] Started plugin
[Main] Sending evaluate request
[Main] Starting getting response
[Plugin] Running
[Plugin] Reading args
[Plugin] Got args, start compute and waiting cancel
[Main] Requested cancellation
[Plugin] Got cancel, cancelling computation
[Plugin] Awaiting computation
[Main] Not ready in time, cancel sent
[Main] No response, killing plugin
[Main] Cancelled
```

Наверняка кое-где недостаточно контролируются ошибки, так что проверяйте, не нужно ли ловить какие-то ещё исключения.

---

На эту заготовку можно добавлять сверху свою логику. Например, можно аналогично пулу потоков завести пул плагинов, и доставлять задания свободному в данный момент плагину.

Comment: А про работу в отдельном appDomain пару слов напишите?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Это пусть кто-нибудь другой напишет :) Вы ж видите, тут малой кровью не обойтись.

Comment: Вы писали, что работа с appDomain медленная из-за сериализациии. А ваш пример быстрее работы с appDomain? У вас тоже ведь сериализация.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Нет, он, думаю, ещё медленнее (в основном за счёт запуска нового процесса).

Answer (score 0):

Нашел один способ принудительного завершения задачи без нарушения работы приложения. Данный способ позволяет завершить задачу, запущенную с параметром *TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning*, зная ID рабочего потока. Основан на вызове функции *ExitThread* в контексте целевого потока с помощью недокументированной функции *RtlRemoteCall*. Способ не работает, если поток бесконечно находится в состоянии ожидания, можно завершить только работающий поток. Т.е это не на 100% надежно, но, я полагаю, получше чем *Thread.Abort*.

Если задача исполняет ваш собственный код, ID рабочего потока легко получить, вызывая из нее функцию GetCurrentThreadId и сохраняя результат в переменной. Если задача исполняет чужой код (например, подгружаемый из внешней DLL), можно его узнать только выборкой из потоков по времени старта задачи.

**Основной класс:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TaskTest
{
    public class TaskKiller
    {
        const int THREAD_ACCESS_TERMINATE = (0x0001);
        const int SYNCHRONIZE = (0x00100000);
        const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = (0x000F0000);
        const int THREAD_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SYNCHRONIZE | 0xFFFF);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenThread(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle,
           uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);


        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();       


        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetCurrentThread();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);        

        [DllImport("ntdll.dll", ExactSpelling = true, EntryPoint = "RtlRemoteCall")]
        static extern int RtlRemoteCall(
    IntPtr Process,
    IntPtr Thread,
    IntPtr CallSite,
    uint ArgumentCount,
    IntPtr Arguments,
    uint PassContext,
    uint AlreadySuspended
    );


        /// <summary>
        /// Завершение потока с указанным ID
        /// </summary>        
        /// <returns>0 при успешном завершении, код NTSTATUS при ошибке</returns>
        public static int KillThreadById(uint threadid)
        {
            IntPtr hModule = (IntPtr)0;
            IntPtr hThread = (IntPtr)0;
            IntPtr unmanagedPointer = (IntPtr)0;
            try
            {
                /*Получение адреса функции ExitThread*/
                hModule = GetModuleHandle(@"kernel32.dll");
                IntPtr pProc = (IntPtr)0;
                pProc = GetProcAddress(hModule, "ExitThread");

                /*Получение дескриптора потока с полным доступом*/
                hThread = TaskKiller.OpenThread(
                    (uint)(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS),
                    false, (uint)threadid);

                IntPtr hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();

                int[] args = new int[] { (int)0 };//массив аргументов для RtlRemoteCall
                unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(args.Length * sizeof(int));//выделение блока неуправлемой памяти
                Marshal.Copy(args, 0, unmanagedPointer, args.Length);//копирование массива в неуправляемую память

                /*Вызов ExitThread в контексте завершаемого потока*/
                int result = RtlRemoteCall(hProcess, hThread, pProc, 1, unmanagedPointer, 0, 0);
                return result;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clean up resources
                if(unmanagedPointer !=(IntPtr)0)Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedPointer);
                if (hThread != (IntPtr)0) TaskKiller.CloseHandle(hThread);
                if (hModule != (IntPtr)0) TaskKiller.CloseHandle(hModule);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Получение ID всех потоков, стартовавших в указанном интервале времени
        /// </summary>        
        public static List<uint> GetThreadsByStartTime(DateTime t1, DateTime t2)
        {
            List<uint> threads = new List<uint>();

            Process pr=Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            using (pr)
            {
                ProcessThreadCollection ths = pr.Threads;

                foreach (ProcessThread th in ths)
                {
                    using (th)
                    {
                        if (th.TotalProcessorTime.TotalMilliseconds > 0)
                        {
                            if (DateTime.Compare(th.StartTime, t1) >= 0 &&
                                DateTime.Compare(th.StartTime, t2) <= 0) threads.Add((uint)th.Id);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return threads;
        }

    }

}
```

**Пример использования:**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace TaskTest
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {        

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                PrintThreads();
            }

            int i = 0;
            uint threadid;//ID рабочего потока        

            DateTime t;//время старта задачи
            Task t1=null;//задача


            void PrintThreads()
            {
                Process pr=Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                using (pr)
                {
                    ProcessThreadCollection ths = pr.Threads;

                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(300);
                    b.AppendLine("Threads: " + ths.Count);
                    foreach (ProcessThread th in ths)
                    {
                        using (th)
                        {
                            b.AppendLine(th.Id + " - " + th.ThreadState.ToString()+" - "+th.StartTime);
                        }
                    }
                    textBox1.Text += b.ToString();
                }
            }


            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                /*Делегат для задачи*/
                Action action = () =>
                {
                    threadid = TaskKiller.GetCurrentThreadId(); //сохранить ID потока для последующего доступа                               

                    while (true)// Just loop.
                    {      
                        i++;                    
                    }
                };

                // Construct an unstarted task            
                t1 = new Task(action,TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);            

                // Launch task             
                t1.Start();
                t = DateTime.Now;//сохранить время старта для последующего использования

                textBox1.Text = "Task started"+Environment.NewLine;
                PrintThreads();
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //Завершение потока, если известен его ID
                textBox1.Text = "-- Before terminating --" + Environment.NewLine;
                PrintThreads();
                textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;

                int res=TaskKiller.KillThreadById(threadid);
                if (res != 0)
                {
                    textBox1.Text += ("Error NTSTATUS=" + res.ToString("X"));
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox1.Text += threadid.ToString() + " is terminated!";
                }
                textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;

                textBox1.Text += "-- After terminating --" + Environment.NewLine;
                PrintThreads();
            }

            private void bTerminate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //Завершение потоков по времени старта
                textBox1.Text = "-- Before terminating --" + Environment.NewLine;
                PrintThreads();
                textBox1.Text += "-----------------------";
                textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;

                List<uint> threads=TaskKiller.GetThreadsByStartTime(
                    t.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
                    t.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                    );

                foreach (uint id in threads)
                {
                    TaskKiller.KillThreadById(id);
                    textBox1.Text += id.ToString() + " is terminated!";
                    textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
                }

                textBox1.Text += "-- After terminating --" + Environment.NewLine;
                PrintThreads();
                textBox1.Text += "-----------------------";

            }   


       } 
    }
```

Comment: Вы даёте достаточно плохой совет. Убивать поток просто нельзя, уж тем более низкоуровневыми средствами через WinAPI. Что если поток в это время держит `lock` на какой-то ресурс? Все аргументы против `Thread.Abort` для вашего случая точно так же применимы.

Comment: Этот способ еще хуже чем `Thread.Abort`. Abort дает хоть какой-то шанс освободить ресурсы!

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Данный метод предназначен для аварийного завершения задачи, которую нельзя завершить другим способом (например, метод из сторонней библиотеки вошел в бесконечный цикл из-за ошибки в алгоритме). Thread.Abort в данном случае может помочь, но не всегда, так как вызываемый сторонний метод может обрабатывать ThreadAbortException и продолжать работу, или вообще зависать при вызове неуправляемого кода (тогда ThreadAbortException не возникнет пока код не вернется в управляемую область). ExitThread гарантированно прибьет поток, если он не в deadlock-е.

Comment: @VadimTagil чем в таком случае ваш вариант лучше чем TerninateThread?

Comment: @VladD ресурс навсегда останется заблокированным. Никто и не обещал, что можно "совсем" без негативных последствий прибить любой поток. Во-первых, для синхронизации потоков, которые потенциально могут быть аварийно завершены, должен использоваться не lock а Mutex (который автоматически переводится в состояние abandoned при аварийном завершении владеющего потока и генерирует исключение при попытке доступа вместо зависания навечно).  Во-вторых, если возникает необходимость аварийного завершения потока, это значит уже все плохо, он завис и может никогда не освободить занятые ресурсы.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov TerminateThread, как оказалось, имеет несколько фатальных недостатков. Во-первых, она не освобождает память, выделенную под стек убиваемого потока. Во-вторых, она не посылает в DllMain загруженных библиотек уведомление DLL_THREAD_DETACH, а CLR похоже зависит от него в плане управления ресурсами потоков. На практике это приводит к тому, что после вызова TerminateThread в управляемом приложении оно может зависнуть или аварийно завершиться в случайных местах. ExitThread избавлена хотя бы от этих недостатков (хотя имеет другие, менее критичные).

Comment: @VadimTagil: Если вы вызываете чужой код, то вы не можете быть уверенным, что он «готов» к аварийному завершению потока. (Представьте себе алгоритм вставки в односвязный список, который реально к такому готов. Представили?) Если вы вызываете собственный код, гораздо проще и дешевле просто починить его, чтобы он нормально реагировал на `CancellationToken`. Кстати, вы уверены, что классы BCL (например, `Dictionary<K, V>`) нормально переживут обрыв потока?

Comment: @VladD Естественно, любые данные, которые поток модифицировал в момент принудительного завершения, могут быть повреждены. Этого избежать невозможно ни одним способом, кроме разве что ведения журнала транзакций как в базах данных.

Comment: @VadimTagil: Ну, если выгрузить этот самый код в отдельный _процесс_, то проблем быть не должно. Данные в другом процессе не влияют на данные в этом процессе.