# Почему зависает и не убивается поток и поднятые в нём потоки? - код внутри

Tags: c#, многопоточность

имеется код вызова потока по нажатию на кнопку

```
StartUp start = new StartUp(this);
        my = new Thread(start.Go);
        my.Start();
```

имеется код завершения потока по нажатию на другую кнопку

```
my.Abort();
```

и сама функция передаваемая в поток

```
public void Go ()
{
    int max = work.max_thread;
label1:
    if (work.keys.Count>0)
    {
        while (count_thread == 0 || count_thread < max)
        {
            Thread myThread = new Thread(web.InD);

            myThread.Start();
            count_thread += 1;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        goto label1;
    }
}
```

Comment: используйте `CancellationToken` вместо `Abort`

Comment: `Abort` - мы его теряем! `goto` - мы его потеряли...

Comment: Почему Abort не помогает - не понятно до конца. goto - мне оч нравится - и чем он хуже того же while , которым можно было бы здесь заменить - непонятно так же

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир GoTo слишком мощная конструкция, которая может использоваться для чего угодно... Для ветвления, циклов и т п. Однако, вы должны достаточно обосновать почему вы используете именно GoTo, а не другой оператор. Ведь посмотрев на GoTo вы не сразу поймете его смысл, а увидев какой-нибудь while вы сразу поймете назначение и смысл кода.

Comment: Как правильно завершать потоки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573594/106

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abort не гарантирует убийство потока. Потом может словить исключение и выполнить Thread.ResetAbort и продолжать выполняться.

Прерывание потока должно быть кооперативной операцией, поэтому нужно использовать `CancellationToken`.

P.S GoTo - это плохой тон и его использование нужно хорошенько обосновать.

Можно им воспользоваться в редких случаях, когда нужно выпрыгнуть из большого числа условий не выполняя большое кол-во проверок статусов.

Comment: Но у автора в коде нет обработки исключений. У приведенного кода вообще нет никаких причин не завершиться при Abort. Скорее всего ошибка, как обычно, в том коде, который автор не показал.

Comment: да, как раз в потоках, которые вызывает прерываемый поток - много кода в обработках try